# Moleculer-Cli inspired project: how to use EJS instead of Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ejs, scaffolding, metalsmith, moleculer

I'm trying to create some scaffolding tool to easily start a project the way I want. I like the way how guys from moleculer do it in their https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-cli

They use Handlebars so now I can do this in my template (for example the one for package.json):

```
"name" : "{{ projectName }}"
```

That worked well but I would prefer to use ejs. 
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to successfully change the init.js file so Metalsmith can chew up something like this:

```
"name" : "<%= projectName %>}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moleculer-cli uses [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js) package which supports ejs, as well.

So, you should change the render variable here: `const render = require("consolidate").handlebars.render;`

Comment: thank you very much, icebob...silly me, that works like a charm. `const { render } = require('consolidate').ejs` does the trick. then i just changed regex test inside init.js to `/<%=([^]+)%>/` to fit ejs pattern. thanks again.